# liquid simulation with Viscosity getting weird (like explosion)

Tags: fluid-simulation

I have a question about fluid setting. (blender 2.92)

I set 3 fluid output with initial speed 3m/s in Y/Z direction in a Domain. (All three inflow are the same)
[image]

Resolution Divisions is set at 32.

I tried to set the parameters of "Viscosity" to 0.1.

In this case I am changing the "Timesteps Max/Min" to "1/1", "2/2" and "3/3".

In the second case the result becomes very weird. (Like the image below)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Why is only "Timesteps Max/Min = 2/2" so weird?

Although I found that the timesteps is set to 2 will be very weird, but this should also be matched with the specific Resolution Divisions.

When Resolution Divisions is set to 30 or 34, there is no such "uncontrollable" simulation.

Or maybe when the simulation starts with "Viscous" liquid settings, it will start to have such unpredictable results with some  parameters settings with specific value?

Are there other settings that can prevent such as these explosion of viscous liquids?

Thanks a lot!

(My settings are below)

[image]
[image]

Comment: resolution 32 with your sizes....is very low. maybe change to 80-90 to get reasonable results

Comment: thanks for your command. I can test any resolution actually. But what I care about is why it seems that a specific resolution value causes this explosion.
Even if I adjust the resolution to a high level, there is a chance that it will happen?